# Stopping `li:hover::before` moving list item's text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get some CSS for `li:hover::before` working but not really sure which properties to change so that the item text does not move even though the bullet content changes (increases in length).

On list item hover I am adding extra characters to the bullet's `content` but I want the characters to prefix the existing one instead of appending to the right and moving the item text.

I have no idea which properties I should be changing to ensure that the text will stay stationary regardless of font size and font itself.
(e.g. transforming an exact number of pixels left isn't much of a solution)

The closest I got was using `"\2002\2002\203a"` for the non-hover `content` but the spaces are a slightly different width than the char I'm using so there is still shifting happening.

The character I'm using is `\203a` or `›`.

I'd ideally like to do this without any JavaScript and am not really too bothered about backwards compatibility with IE8 and other browsers that people shouldn't be using in this day and age.

#### Desired look:

```
not hovered:     > Text
hovered        >>> Text
```

#### example html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### css

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 2.5em;
}
li {
    padding-left: 1.2em;
    text-indent: -1em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
li::before {
      content: "\203a";
      padding-right: 0.3em;
}
li:hover::before {
    content: "\203a\203a\203a";
    /* ??? */
}
```

#### fiddle:

[And the obligatory JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7y6Z/)

Comment: Did you try adding `position: absolute` to `li::before`?

Comment: that's a step closer. it's now (unhovered) `>    Text` and (hovered) `>>> Text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes to the CSS:

```
li {
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
}

li::before {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: right;
   left: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7y6Z/5/).

Comment: Thanks, I guess my first mistake was assuming that my solution would be confined to `li:hover::before` and I kept going around in circles from there. [Result in case you'd be interested](http://indivisibleindustries.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you make `li` have a relative position, `li::before` have an absolute position and (the most important part) `text-align:right;` you'll get what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/p7y6Z/6/

You may want to adjust positioning, but this should get you started.

Comment: Have it working now - any size, any font -- thanks. [Result in case you'd be interested](http://indivisibleindustries.com)